# delphi, android, starting an application, _system Pansichar

Tags: android, delphi

To run/start an android application (name of the application = server) in delphi I found that the code must be:

_system(Pansichar('open /data/app/server.oddex'));

the  problem is that Panshichar is not longer supported in delphi embacardero XE. And after reading many solutions to this problem, I could not find any concrete solution to this specific command, _system

Any help?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

`MarshaledAString` is an alias for `PAnsiChar` that you can use for Android.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.MarshaledAString

Comment: Thanks!! However, it seems that my path to the file is not correct because the application does not start. What is the correct path /data/app/server/? no path?

Comment: I have installed X-plore and I found the correct path to my application. However the command: _system(MarshaledAString('open /data/app/com.embarcadero.Server-2.apk')) does not work

Comment: @Francisco that sounds like a different problem

Answer (score 1):

You should not being `system()` to run an APK.  The correct way to start another installed app is to use an Android [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) instead:

[Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

You can use Delphi's JNI bridge framework to access Android APIs, for example:

[Sending Android Intents from Delphi (Part 1)](http://www.danieleteti.it/2013/09/26/sending-android-intents-from-delphi-part-1/)

[Sending Android Intents from Delphi (Part 2)](http://www.danieleteti.it/2014/01/13/sending-android-intents-from-delphi-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, in my case, I have to launch an apk that it is not designed to be launched for an external apk. Video players, browsers, etc can be launch just passing them a file. This is not my case. I cannot find a single example showing how to launch a 'normal' apk. Only that android:exported="true" has to placed in the Manifest file. This case is really more complex...really more complex...

Comment: "I have to launch an apk that it is not designed to be launched" - then why are you trying to launch it? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why is the APK not launchable? Why is it not installed as a normal app? An Intent can launch a specific app, it is not limited to just launching a default app for a file.